# Snap svg Snap.animation() function

Tags: javascript, snap.svg, svg-animate

I'm trying to create an animation with many stage of changes, does Snap.animation() allow to do that or i have to use css3 animation ? feel like the docs still missing something

Comment: If you mean sequenced animations, you can do this, but needs a bit of extra programming. An example would be something like http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-animateframe

Comment: Thanks mate, this is what i'm looking for. However it can be a bit tedious if the animation contains  lots of stages..... i guess i'll have to stick with this solution for a while

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by stages, that the script above won't do (or that is tedious that could be improved) ? If it makes sense, I may adapt it.

Comment: Btw, here is an updated one I did a while back which allows callbacks and different elements.. http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-animateframeel2

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for your help. How do i give credits to people ? I'm new to this site...

Comment: I've posted an answer with that code, just accept it and mark useful below if you found that answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create a sequencing function or plugin that takes your animations in turn, without needing to code every one. You can pass these in as an array for example. Here is some code I have done previously.

In the array, you pass it an object..

el: the element to act on

animation: The animation to perform (eg an object containing attributes to animate to)

dur: The duration

easing: The easing

startFunc: An optional callback to run for each 'frame'.

Note, you could probably include some blank frames (animate a attribute to the same value or one that doesn't exist or doesn't matter) if you wanted things like delays.

```
function nextFrame ( frameArray,  whichFrame ) {
    if( whichFrame >= frameArray.length ) { return }

    if( typeof frameArray[ whichFrame ].startFunc === 'function' ) { 
      frameArray[ whichFrame ].startFunc.call(frameArray[ whichFrame ].el) 
    };

    frameArray[ whichFrame ].el.animate(    frameArray[ whichFrame ].animation, 
                    frameArray[ whichFrame ].dur, 
                    frameArray[ whichFrame ].easing,
                    nextFrame.bind(null,  frameArray, whichFrame + 1 ) 
    );

}


// Example of use

var r = s.rect(100,100,100,100,20,20).attr({ stroke: '#123456', 'strokeWidth': 20, fill: 'red' });
var c = s.circle(50,50,50).attr({ stroke: '#123456', 'strokeWidth': 20, fill: 'blue' });

var g = s.group(r,c);

var myFrames = [
    {   el: g,  animation: { transform: 'r360,150,150' }, dur: 1000, easing: mina.bounce },
    {   el: r,  animation: { transform: 't100,-100s2,3', fill: 'green' }, dur: 1000, easing: mina.bounce },
    {   el: r,  animation: { transform: 't100,100' }, dur: 1000, easing: mina.bounce, startFunc: sayHello },
    {   el: g,  animation: { transform: 's2,1' }, dur: 1000, easing: mina.bounce },
    {   el: r,  animation: { transform: 's1,2' }, dur: 1000, easing: mina.bounce },
    {   el: c,  animation: { transform: 's1,1' }, dur: 1000, easing: mina.bounce }];

nextFrame( myFrames, 0 );

function sayHello() {
    alert('hello, this is me ==> ' + this);
}
```

[example](http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-animateframeel2)